# Any product of two transpositions is in a normal subgroup $H$ of $S_n$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm trying to prove that any product of two transpositions is in a normal subgroup $H$ of $S_n$.

I know that a normal subgroup of $S_n$ has index 2 and hence contains no transpositions. And but I don't think I understand what it means by any product of two transpositions is in $H$ when $H$ contains no transpositions. I thought of it as any permutations can be written as a product of transpositions but I am quite lost.

Comment: $S_n$ has the normal subgroup $A_n$ of even permutations. The sign of a product of two transpositions is $1$, so it's in $A_n$.

Comment: @Vinícious Novelli So I actually proved that $A_n$ is the normal subgroup of $S_n$ in the proceeding exercise. I’m not sure if I can use something to solve a preceeding exercise. Anyhow. What do you mean by the sign of a product is 1?

Comment: Well, you have the sign homomorphism $\sigma: S_n \to \{-1,+1\}$ (can you use that this is a group homomorphism?). Then, $A_n$ is just the kernel of $\sigma$, so it's a normal subgroup (kernels of homomorphisms are always normal subgroups).

Comment: @ViníciusNovelli Is there a way to prove this without using the fact that $A_n$ is the normal subgroup of $S_n$?

Comment: $S_n/H$ is the group of order $2$, and since $H$ contains no transpositions, all transpositions map to the non-identity element of $S_n/H$. Can you continue?

Comment: @SteveD I know this is a quotient map. were $\pi:S_n \rightarrow S_n/H$ is given by $a \mapsto aH$. In this case, since $S_n/H$  only has two elements, i.e., $eH$ and $aH$... I'm lost again...

Comment: Every transposition belongs to the **same** coset. What does that tell you? What does it mean for two elements to be in the same coset? Give it some effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This proof is by @ViníciusNovelli and is given in the comments.*

Since $A_n\lhd  S_n$ and $\operatorname{sgn}:S_n\to \{1,-1\}$ with $\ker(\operatorname{sgn})=A_n$, the sign of two transpositions is $1$, so their product must be in $A_n$. So let $H=A_n$.